# Flutter app does not build on ios when cloud firestore is added

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

When I add the cloud_firestore dependency to my flutter app, the ios build is failing.

The build failure is as follows...

```
    fatal error: module map file
    '/Users/myUserName/src/MobileApp/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/openssl_grpc/BoringSSL-GRPC.modulemap' not found
    1 error generated.
```

The flutter app builds an runs on android fine, and I have followed the installation instructions for cloud_firestore for flutter on both ios and android.

Comment: I have build for the iOS simulator today with the latest stable flutter version. However, firestore is not yet fully implemented in my app, but some methods are already referenced. So I guess it should work I.e. you have some issue in your code or IDE

Comment: its the problem with the pods, try any tutorial for adding firebase to ios